# In a managed_file upload field, how do I prevent an overflow with long file names?

Tags: 7, forms, theming

I have a form using the field type of `managed_upload`. Things are working fine accept when the file name is long.

[image]

Given the snippet of code, below. Might there be a way to override CSS or inject any CSS to keep the `fieldset` or this `span` from overrunning the `sidebar_second` region?

```
  $form['file_fs'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Files'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $form['file_fs']['file'] = [
    '#title' => t('Documents'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file', ,
    '#upload_location' => 'private://',

  ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a class to the fieldset and adding a class to the css file of your theme.

Add something like this to the fieldset.

`'#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-fieldset'));`

And then something like this to your css file

`.my-fieldset {max-width: 100%;}`